# Keep Two Layouts Centre of each other with Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I was trying to put two layouts one after another and keeping the next layout in the center of the first one. The layout in XML is similar to the following

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The output is like the following

[image]

The problem is that the second layout's height is variable and if it's bigger (let's say 170dp instead of 70dp) than the first one then the output is

[image]

Part of the second layout has been cut off. How can I bring both of them inside and keep the second layout still in the center of the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution for your problem is to use a `Barrier` at the Bottom of the buttons and set the `constraintBottom` to the `Barrier` and set the `constraintTop` to the parent to both Buttons. Like the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button" />
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="button,button1"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: screen result]

Answer (score 0):

set layout gravity of constraintlayout to center can help you